# fail to connect denso hs45452 robot

Tags: ros, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone, I'm working on a tutorial http://wiki.ros.org/denso_robot_ros/Tutorials/How%20to%20control%20an%20RC8%20with%20MoveIt%21

version indigo, about How to control an RC8 with MoveIt! .

After I finished the tutorial, I launched bringup file, but get this error,

```
[ERROR] [1548245807.887070308]: Failed to change to slave mode. (83500126)
```

And I checked the teach pendant, it says error code `(83500126)` needing registering(invoke source, PC). But I have followed the tutorial and registered b-cap slave. Because of this error, I got the following error

```
[ERROR] [1548245821.516886560]: MoveItSimpleControllerManager: Action client not connected: hs45452/arm_controller/follow_joint_trajectory
```

Would you like to help me on this problem?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/313517/fail-to-connect-denso-hs45452-robot/) by [shyreckdc](https://answers.ros.org/users/29354/shyreckdc/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2019-01-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found the problem, after I registered following the tutorial, the teach pendant should restart.

---

Originally posted by [shyreckdc](https://answers.ros.org/users/29354/shyreckdc/) with karma: 16 on 2019-01-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0